# Method of Characteristics for a Conservation Law

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the PDE

$$
u_{t}+uu_{x}=0
$$
with the arbitrary initial condition of
$$
u(x,0)=f(x).
$$
I am trying to write the equation I'd need to solve to find the solution of the PDE at an arbitrary point in space and time. I believe that it would be
$$
u(x,t)=f(x-u(x,t)\cdot t).
$$
Is this accurate? So, if for instance I had the initial condition of 
$$
f(x)=\sin(\pi x)
$$
would the equation I'd need to solve be
$$
u(x,t)=\sin(\pi (x-u(x,t)\cdot t))?
$$

I'm a computational chemist so am not as well-versed in the mathematics of solving PDEs as I would like, so a quick sanity check would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: This is correct. The method of characteristics leads to the general solution : $u=f(x-ut)$ and with the initial condition the solution expressed on implicit form is $u=\sin\left(\pi(x-ut)\right)$.

Comment: @JJacquelin Thank you very much for confirming that for me. Greatly appreciated!